# How to export large dataset collection of mongodb to CSV file on button click via node express

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, csv

I have db contain large dataset -  json objects - (array) around ~10k i have for now. I want to to fetch all from db and generate csv and download via route..

Here's sample json object:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56bc3a7da30befd952349542"),
    "asin" : "B00T2Q1S18",
    "searchRank" : 113,
    "name" : "FREEing Racing Miku 2014 (EV Mirai Version) Figma Action Figure",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-11T07:38:37.774Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-02-11T07:44:07.667Z"),
    "linkIds" : [
        "25b1071a9e908806338c4106"
    ],
    "price" : {
        "amazon" : 50.49
    },
    "ranks" : [
        {
            "number" : 43619,
            "category" : "Baby Toys"
        }
    ],
    "upc" : ""
}
```

Is there any better npm (node) library which can converts my json collection to csv..

Though I have tried those but on large dataset they aren't working.

- papaparse / babyparse
- json2csv

Is there any other libs that you know better or any other better approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with many libs and at last I found one - a great npm module which handles large dataset problem nicely....

https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvwriter

exported upto 5 lacs + json objects (for now)..

Here is my small [demo large dataset json to csv exporter app via node, express, mongodb](https://github.com/narainsagar/demo-large-dataset-json-to-csv-exporter)

Hope this helps others as well, when they come over here.

Cheers,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before using an npm library called [csv-builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-builder). Based on my experience I can say that it gives good performance and It is quite easy to implement.

I have made a CSV of about **2 LAC rows** and around 8-10 columns,with manipulation in between using this library.